# RXJava share() not working with Observable.create()

Tags: java, rx-java

This code

```
public class ConnectObs {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Observable<Integer> intsObservable = Observable.just(1, 2);
    intsObservable = intsObservable.share();

    intsObservable.subscribe(s->System.out.println("A " + s));
    intsObservable.subscribe(s->System.out.println("B " + s));

    intsObservable  = Observable.create(s -> {
        s.onNext(1);
        s.onNext(2);
    });
    intsObservable = intsObservable.share();

    intsObservable.subscribe(s->System.out.println("C " + s));
    intsObservable.subscribe(s->System.out.println("D " + s));
  }
}
```

Produces results for A,B and C.  But not for D - why is that?

Results below:

```
A 1
A 2
B 1
B 2
C 1
C 2
```

Answer (score 2):

The important difference between `Observable.just` and your custom Observable (which is not constructed safely by the way) is that you didn't complete the stream so the `C` subscription is still active when the `D` subscription happens so `D` just waits around for more emissions that don't come.

Your creation should look like this:

```
Observable.<Integer> create(s -> {
        s.onNext(1);
        s.onNext(2);
        s.onCompleted();
})
//prevent MissingBackpressureException
.onBackpressureBuffer();
```

To be a bit friendlier to the subscribers you might add `unsubscribe` checks too:

```
Observable.<Integer> create(s -> {
        s.onNext(1);
        if (!s.isUnsubscribed())
            s.onNext(2);
        if (!s.isUnsubscribed())
            s.onCompleted();
}).onBackpressureBuffer();
```